# On CW posts, what does the little percentage mean?

Tags: support, community-wiki

[image] (more [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756))

And how does SO decide which username to put there?

Comment: Since the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15075) appears to conflict with [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15078) that is as authoritative as possible (quoting Atwood), it may be best to switch which one is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 40% of the text was written by Mike Duncan. The user name with the most % is placed there.

Comment: This is wrong. The true answer is "sum the total size of all line contributions (insertions or deletions) from any given author in a revision, with a small bonus multiplier of 2x for the original author".

Answer (score 13):

Jeff describes it [on his blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/):

> I simply sum the total size of all line contributions (insertions or deletions) from any given author in a revision, with a small bonus multiplier of 2x for the original author. We report the highest percentage of authorship in the final revision.

Comment: Sadly enough, this is the only correct answer here. (Sad because accepted answer is wrong)

Answer (score 2):

After so many edits, the % starts to reflect who "owns" the most content on the post.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage is to show that certain a person have contributed the most to this post, and how much he contributed. That allows you to quickly tell who put the most effort into the post. Sort of a way to honor that person for writing/organizing information.